# dynamics crm silverlight dropdown cut off in a form

Tags: silverlight, drop-down-menu, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I created my own dropdown in Silverlight 5 and added it as a web resource to a dynamics CRM 2013 form. I added it to a form field with height 1. When I open the dropdown the panel that shows its contents is hidden behind the form fields below the dropdown (in the example below behind the "created by" field).

```
=========================V      <-- Dropdown
Created by        John Doe      <-- The field below the dropdown (hides dropdown)
```

How can I make the dropdown panel be visible when it is opened?

I could set the height of the form field containing my dropdown to a bigger value but then I have much blank space between the dropdown and the field below. I don't want that, because it defeats the whole point of a dropdown.

This is NOT what I want:

```
=========================V      <-- Dropdown


                                <-- much blank space


Created by        John Doe      <-- The field below the dropdown
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant, the silverlight web resource is bounded by the limits of the web resource on the form and cant place anything outside of it. You could look at other options for input such as an auto complete box maybe?